# How to test $location and .search() in a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a simple service that has a number of methods to retrieve various values from a URL:

```
app.service('urlInterpSrv', function($location) {
    return {
        getCartID : function() {
            return $location.search().getCartID;
        },
        getUserAddress : function() {
            return $location.search().getUserAddress;
        },
        getShippingCountry : function() {
            return $location.search().getShippingCountry;
        },
        getCookie : function() {
            return $location.search().getCookie;
        },
        getUsername : function() {
            return $location.search().getUsername;
        }
    };
});
```

I call these in my controllers simply via:

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartController', function($scope, urlInterpSrv, $rootScope) {

    $scope.getCartID = urlInterpSrv.getCartID();
    $scope.getShippingCountry = urlInterpSrv.getShippingCountry();

});
```

Three questions? Should i be testing the service explicitly, or the controller, or both?

I have tried testing the service explicitly via:

```
describe('urlInterpSrv', function(){

    var $location;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_urlInterpSrv_, _$location_) {
        this.urlInterpSrv = _urlInterpSrv_;
        $location = _$location_;
    }));


    it('should getCartID from url', function(){
        $location.path('/?getCartID=0087598');
        expect(this.urlInterpSrv.getCartID).toEqual(0087598);
    });

});
```

However i get the error:

```
Expected Function to equal 87598.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$location.path` [doesn't change 'search' part of url](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes), it changes 'path' part and encodes `?` character instead.

Numbers with leading zero should be avoided because they can be [treated as octals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers) in JS.

It isn't `$location`'s job to parse primitives in parameter values, `getCartID` equals to '0087598' string, not to 87598.

```
it('should getCartID from url', function(){
    $location.url('/?getCartID=0087598');
    expect(this.urlInterpSrv.getCartID()).toEqual('0087598');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asserting function, not its returned value.  Try:

```
expect(this.urlInterpSrv.getCartID()).toEqual(0087598);
```

Comment: thanks, tried your suggestion still get the error: Expected undefined to equal 87598.

Comment: Should i be using 'this' at all? Considering the methods in my service are not using 'this' instead the literall notation?

Comment: No, you should not.  Try without `this`, what will be the result?

Comment: You should also add `var urlInterpSrv` before `beforeEach` statement.

Comment: removed this and added var $location, var $location; still getting the same error.

Comment: One moment, I`ll try to create a plunkr with your case.

Comment: at the guess, i 'think' i need to spyOn the object/service and method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90431/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-oam-psy).

Comment: thanks for the efforts. Estus above has pointed out the error that i was making.

Answer (score 0):

coould you try below.. you can execute the function first and then compare the results

```
it('should getCartID from url', function(){
    $location.path('/?getCartID=0087598');
    var cartId = this.urlInterpSrv.getCartID();
    expect(cartId).toEqual(0087598);
});
```

Comment: thanks, however i get the error: Expected undefined to equal 87598.